# Update For all loans WHERE user_id=? in CASE when DATEDIFF() >0. Error 1242 and 1093

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff, mysql-error-1093, mysql-error-1242

I have this query

```
Update loans set fine = case 
when DATEDIFF((
(SELECT * from (SELECT loans.due_date FROM loans where users_id = 1)  AS l1)) 
,DATE(NOW())) > 0 THEN 1
ELSE fine 
END 
WHERE users_id =1;
```

From table

```
+-------------+
| Field       |
+-------------+
| users_id    |
| books_isbn  |
| aquire_date |
| due_date    |
| fine        |
+-------------+
```

It's work with user that have just one 'loans' but I don't know how to make it work with several 'loans' of one user. =(

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results are helpful.  Non-working code, less so.

Comment: I wanted to increase the fine depending on the number of overdue days. DATEDIFF * coefficient.
THEN 1 it's just for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a query to look someting like this:

```
Update loans l
    set fine = 1
    where users_id = 1 and l.due_date < curdate();
```

It is a little tricky to figure out the exact logic without sample data and desired results.

Comment: oh thank you, I obviously complicated the task =) took the first available way of comparing the dates and forgot about the others